# Problem using OAuth2 Bearer Token in Azure B2C REST Call

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am calling a REST API with a bearer token from my self-asserted-login technical profile. I have placed the call in the validation profiles as below -

`<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">False</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">none</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.signuporsignin</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            **<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SecureREST-AccessToken" ContinueOnError="false"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-SignIn" ContinueOnError="true" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive"/>**
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>`

I can trace that the REST call is being made successfully with the bearer token in the header. However, the "login-NonInteractive" is not working. It is giving error "invalid username or password". However, if  I  remove below two steps the "login-NonInteractive"  works fine.

It seems like there is a side effect from OAuth2 enabled REST call and "login-NonInteractive". They should be completely unrelated but the strange behavior halting my production.

```
        **<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SecureREST-AccessToken" ContinueOnError="false"/>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-UserMigration-LocalAccount-SignIn" ContinueOnError="true" />**
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Should be unrelated. Post a link to where we can find your policy files.