# Azure B2C - REST Call with OAuth2 Bearer Token Prevents Subsequent Login

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

*I consider this a duplicate of question [Problem using OAuth2 Bearer Token in Azure B2C REST Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62051069/problem-using-oauth2-bearer-token-in-azure-b2c-rest-call), but I don't have enough reputation to add my repro links as a comment, so I'm raising this second question in the hope they can be merged..*

Using B2C custom policy files, if I make a call to acquire an access token (which I could then use to make secure REST calls), *followed* by an attempt to sign in, I get an "Invalid username or password" message at the sign-in - even though the login credentials are correct.

If I skip the call to get the access token, then the sign in is fine (using the same credentials that fail above).

Link to my policy files:
https://github.com/TechedOff/adb2c-rest-repro.
The `DemoTrustFrameworkBase` and `DemoTrustFrameworkExtensions` are taken directly from the Starter Pack (with my tenant etc filled in).  `DemoSigninOnlyNoRest` is the one that works; `DemoSigninOnlyWithRest` is the failing one, and the only extra it has in it is the minimum possible to get an access token.

As per the comment on the other question, the call to get an access token *should* be unrelated to signing in, but somehow it's definitely throwing the B2C sign-in off.

Comment: You can't really merge questions with another question.  You can mark a question a duplicate of another.  And sometimes answers from two questions are merged under one question.  I've added a link to the other question (which also then has a reference at the side on that question linking back to here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `login-noninteractive`, where you use `defaultvalue="x"`, also add `AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"`.

I believe the issue is that the `scope`  and `grant_type` are getting set to a value in the REST API technical profile. And then is not being set appropriately in the subsequent `login-noninteractive` call, `defaultvalue` only applies if the value is `null`. `AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"` will overwrite an existing value.

You could also use different claim names, and use `partnerclaimType` to send it with the right name.